# Can you change the difficulty during strikeforce missions and still get the achievements?

Tags: achievements, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Okay so I'm playing the game on veteran to get the achievements, I was wondering if you can lower the difficulty on strikeforce missions and change it to veteran when nearly finished. So I can still get the veteran achievement. I want the good ending so that's why I'm doing it. Strikeforce missions on veteran are a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about changing the difficulty, but after many tried and failed attempts on Veteran difficulty, I think I found an easy strategy to beat FOB Spectre.

I start by calling all my infantry to the ComSat station. I then take control of the CLAW near the power transformer. I left the cooling tower unguarded.  Controlling the CLAW, I just sit at the power transformer and take out the incoming infantry and drones.  This strategy allows me to keep the CLAW alive, while my incoming reinforcements continue to guard the sat station. The location of the CLAW also allows me to provide some cover for the infantry at the ComSat station by shooting incoming drones.

Once the cooling tower and ComSat get taken down, I walk the claw into the the building for the final showdown.  Once inside, I was able to use the CLAW to keep the enemy forces at bay until just over a minute remaining.  At that point the enemy took out my CLAW.  I finished the mission as infantry, running and gunning into the factory to blow up any EMPs that were placed.

This method worked out well for me, and allowed me to beat the level the first time I tried it this way.  I could not break the 5 minute mark before I tried it this way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the difficulty. They do however expire so you can still progress through the game on Veteran to get the achievement.

Each strike force mission is an achievement in itself, but are not affected by difficulty, so to get these achievements you could just attempt and fail until they expire and then play on the easiest mode after completing Veteran. You won't be able to access the different endings to the game without completing them though.

Apparently its nigh impossible to do the strike force missions on Veteran as the AI has god-like aim and RTS is a bit difficult on a console.

Answer (score 0):

I did secon chance and I.D.E on Vet without realising it, now I just have to do FOB Spectre and Shipwrecked which are both impossible. I did them on regular but they never counted on the career recordmasnot said ' is still at risk'
By this, to get the ending, you must do them on the campaign difficulty :(

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I lasted almost the entire time inside the building. I put my CLAW on the stairs near the inside turret and just watched the map for enemy forces and took them out. My CLAW was destroyed around 2 min left and I lasted the rest of the time with infantry.